# Altium supplier search: components with cut and tape packaging are never shown?

Tags: altium

When I enter the manufacturing code for different components, I seem to only get options for tape and reel packing, but not cut and tape packaging. Is it possible that there is a setting that prevents cut and tape packaged components from showing? And if so, how can I change it so it shows also components with cut and tape packing, if available?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (partial) result. I don't see any options under preferences in AD20 to limit packaging types.

[image]

The cut tape (and customized reels) is something done by distributors so if you have distributors selected who don't do it, you won't get any results.